# Confirmation Popup Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am looking to add a confirmation message to my application, if the user clicks submit then the action is performed else it cancels the event.

I've got a route which is handled through express, but when the event is cancelled i don't want the back-end code to be run.

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help :)

Comment: You mean confirmation message? Can you post more information or paste your code snippet. Based on your current information it seems you need to handle this logic in frontend instead touching the backend part

Comment: Wouldnt it just be a simple if statement, if true then run code else cancel event. Im still learning the ins and outs of javascript so im a bit of a noob.

Comment: If you wanna make the confirmation message popup in frontend, just handle this event in frontend. It will keep the architecture clean. Btw, you can post your code for better question

Comment: This is my backend code, i just dont want this to run if the user answers no. https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=QaBGfI8o0g

Comment: I go through your code it only shows a express router. I still did not get your intention. If the user answers no, you can just block the request from your client side. Then the router will not be triggered as expected

Comment: Oh right i guess i was overthinking it. Sorry for wasting your time :)

Comment: That's fine. Keep moving and learning

Answer (score 0):

You should handle this confirmation logic in frontend part before sending request to backend. This will simplify the architecture of your app